# How can I change 'WORD' to 'Word' in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

I am using SQLite as a database. I have a column containing users name.

```
Name
----
ALEX
DAVID
JOHN
PAUL
```

How can I amend all rows, so their name is like 'Alex', 'David', 'John', 'Paul' i.e. first letter is uppercase and the rest is lowercase?

Comment: With [lower()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#lower).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT substr(Name, 1, 1) || lower(substr(Name, 2)) AS NiceName
FROM ...etc, etc...
```

should work.